# Guice - Default binding for MapBinder

Tags: java, guice

I am using `MapBinder` to map keys to their respective implementations. Right now I have something like this:

```
MapBinder<String, Processor> processor
                = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, Processor.class);
        processor.addBinding("a1").to(a1Processor.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        processor.addBinding("a2").to(a2Processor.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        processor.addBinding("a3").to(a3Processor.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

It is working the way that it is supposed to. But right now I am thinking of creating a `DefaultProcessor` and binding any `String` other than `a2` and `a3` to this `DefaultProcessor`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What you want is not possible as MapBinder provides you with a Map<Key, Value>. What you are asking is to break Map's contract. It cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**Javadocs**](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) of `MapBinder`

> An API to bind multiple map entries separately, only to later inject
>   them as a complete map.

So what you are asking in your question is not possible to achieve via MapBinder.

Although you can write a wrapper around the `Map<String, Processor>` and use it.

Suggestion:

```
@Singleton
class StringProcessorWrapper {

    private final Map<String, Processor> processorMap;
    private final Processor defaultProcessor;

    @Inject
    public StringProcessorWrapper(Map<String, Processor> processorMap, @Named("default") Processor defaultProcessor) {
        this.processorMap = processorMap;
        this.defaultProcessor = defaultProcessor;
    }

    public Processor get(String key) {
        return processorMap.getOrDefault(key, defaultProcessor);
    }
}
```

For this to work you will have to add a binding in your guice module's `configure` method like this:

```
bind(Processor.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("default")).to(DefaultProcessor.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

Now you can inject the `StringProcessor` wrapper and use it.

This suggestion is valueable when you need to use the `Map` at a lot of places. For a single class, you can just inject the default and use it when key is missing.

If you just want to use the map and avoid adding a separate default binding, you can add a 4th binding in your MapBinder with `"default"` key and in the `get` method of `StringProcessorWrapper` do something like this:

```
processorMap.getOrDefault(key, processorMap.get("default"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! To use this I just need to @Inject in another class and use the `get` method passing the key as the parameter, right?

Comment: Yes, you will have to Inject this class using @Inject. You will also have to add a binding for default processor.

Comment: Something like this `processor.addBinding("default").to(DefaultProcessor.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);` right?

Comment: No, this one will be separate. Your map will just contain the a1, a2, a3 keys. You will have to do something like `bind(Processor.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("default")).to(DefaultProcessor.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);`

Comment: Shouldn't I use the `DefaultProcessor` class in the `defaultProcessor` variable and in the constructor? You used the `Processor` class.

Comment: Good to use interface rather than implementation :) I updated my answer.